# it costs $30. or it is $30.?

Tags: difference

Here are two sentences related to money.

> The clothing is $30.
>   The clothing costs $30.

What is difference in meaning between these two?

Comment: *The clothing is $30*, could be interpreted as "costing $30", but you can't know for sure without some context.

Comment: No context. I'm learning a daily english speaking. in there, I found 'How much would it cost to wash my car?', I was curious because i thought of like this 'How much is it to wash my car?'.

Comment: In such context you are asking about the cost, so there is no difference.

Comment: I see. if the speaker is using the word 'cost', he/she seems interested in the cost. thank you. :)

Comment: When talking about prices (with or without explicitly using "cost"), the speaker is **always** interested in cost (or value) otherwise they wouldn't mention the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The clothing is $30.* is more common in spoken language. For example, the following conversation may take place between a customer and a vendor:

> **Customer**: How much is this dress?
>
> **Vendor**: It's $30.

In written language, *The clothing costs $30.* is more common. It is also slightly more formal.